# Is it possible to inherit F# type provider from another one

Tags: inheritance, f#, type-providers

Here is what I tried to do:

```
open Microsoft.FSharp.Core.CompilerServices
open Microsoft.FSharp.Data.TypeProviders

[<TypeProvider>]
type MySqlDataConnection(connectionString: string) as this = 
    inherit SqlDataConnection // Error: This 'inherit' declaration 
    // specifies the inherited type but no arguments. Consider 
    // supplying arguments, e.g. 'inherit BaseType(args)'
```

So is it possible to inherit a type provider from another one in F#?

Comment: I think this was already asked before. Please see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1619567/type-inheritance-in-f). It's possible to inherit from another type provider with `inherit` and specifying the arguments list.

Comment: No, this is different - as you may find, I tried to use "inherit", with and without (...). It seems the problem is: when you're trying to use a type provider somewhere in code, F# expects you invoke it to generate a new type rather than use it as is.